# About Official Lua5.3 Implementation: Write Barrier

Tags: algorithm, lua, garbage-collection

As this [article](http://wiki.luajit.org/New-Garbage-Collector) about LUA gc mentiond, looking at "Tri-Color Incremental Mark & Sweep", at the end of that section,

> This is the GC algorithm used by Lua 5.1/5.2 and LuaJIT 1.x/2.0. It's an enhancement of the linked list algorithm from Lua 5.0. Tables use backward barriers, all other traversable objects use forward barriers.

I read the source code of `lua_rawset`
it uses `luaC_barrierback(L, hvalue(o), L->top-1);`
It's a common sense that barrier back will slow down gc progress(grayagain and re-traverse the table object).

My Question is WHY the author chooses barrierback instead of barrierforward (speed up gc performance) ON lua table write??? any advantages?

Comment: Consider asking this in the Lua mailing list.